# How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the UK, particularly for weak or borderline students?

Tags: thesis, masters

> **Related:** [*How does the admissions process work for PhD. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

When applying to a PhD program in **UK** (*where GRE is not accepted*), how does the admissions process work? If an applicant is weak in a particular area, is it possible to offset that by being strong in a different area?

Note that this question originated from [this meta answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/what-should-we-do-with-the-can-i-get-into-x-program-with-3-xx-gpa/1563). Please feel free to edit the question to improve it.

**Note.** I am interested in engineering desciplines.

Comment: I would VTC, but do not want to mod hammer the question. The [US one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly) is not a good question for the SE system, but we got so many questions that we decided to make an exception. I don't see the need for any other country, but when/if it becomes an issue, we can address it then.

Comment: It varies. Some have strict admission procedures, some are interview-based.

Comment: Even the concept of a PhD "program" is pretty unknown in the UK. You get accepted, given a studentship and start research on day 1 (no coursework whatsoever). It's far less structured than the USA. Your question might be better phrased as "how do PhD admissions differ between the UK and the USA?" but maybe even that is too broad.

Comment: It has been two years, we have no answers and considerable controversy about whether this should exist. So, I am going to mod-hammer it closed...if others reconsider and want to answer, you can either vote-to-reopen or open a post on meta.